# Allegro 5 on Raspberry pi

Tags: bitmap, debian, raspberry-pi, allegro5

I just started working on RPi. I'm writting a program which involves making photos (bmp files) and analyzing some pixels. I'm using allegro 5 library and i got a 'basic' problem with function al_load_bitmap. I'm unable to to load bitmap. First lines of code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "allegro-5.1.8/build/lib/Headers/allegro5/allegro.h"
#include "allegro-5.1.8/build/lib/Headers/allegro5/allegro_image.h"

using namespace std;

int main () 
{
unsigned char r, g, b;
ALLEGRO_BITMAP  *tape_image ;

al_init();
al_init_image_addon();
al_init_iio_addon(); 


system("raspistill -o /home/pi/Praca/photo.bmp -t 1");

tape_image = al_load_bitmap("/home/pi/Praca/photo.bmp ");

if(!tape_image) {

cout << "Error! Couldn't load bitmap." <<endl;
getchar();
return 0; 
   } 
...
```

as you can see program is making bitmap and then i want to work with it. But program is unable to load bitmap. 
IDE is Geany 1.22
Compiler g++ -L/usr/local.lib -lallegro_main -lallegro_image -lallegro
And i had to add also this $(pkg-config --libs allegro-5 allegro_main-5 allegro_image-5

Comment: Well, is tape_image NULL? We can't see your screen, you have to tell us. Do you really have a bitmap at "/home/pi/Praca/photo.bmp "? Why is there a space at the end of the filename?

Comment: Well, bitmap is created with line: system("raspistill -o /home/pi/Praca/photo.bmp -t 1"); and it appears on RPi. Does this space matters? It is NULL since this message "Error! Couldn't load bitmap." pops up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add

```
-e bmp
```

to raspistill call line.

Comment: Thanks man. I didn't know about that encoding thing. One more thing, do you know if it's possible to make it faster? With this -e is taking some extra time.

Comment: No, can't help in this case. I don't know how it works internally, seems like it receives jpeg picture directly from hardware cam and then unpacks it to bmp. If there were way to get raw picture and skip jpeg encoding step that would speed up process for sure.